# GridView DataFormatString Doesn't Always Work

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataformat

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 gridview displaying the results of a simple data table.  The Gridview's columns are explicitly defined with one displaying the values of a decimal field.  That column is set with a DataFormatString of {0:C}.  When I view it on my local development machine, it outputs the values correctly (applies the currency format as expected).  As soon as I deploy it to my integration server, the formatting does not apply.  I have verified that the code is the same,  I have verified that the database is the same.  The only difference is the web server.  I am running my local copy via the built-in web server in vs 2005 and the integration server is running IIS 6.0.  I have other apps on the same integration server that have a gridview applying a format string with no problems.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="BEGIN_BALANCE" HeaderText="Beginning Balance" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
<ItemStyle Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

On my local machine, the value 52393.59 is diplayed as $52,393.59 where as on the integration server it is display as 52393.5900.

Does anyone have any idea what I may be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: can you put that line of code when you are applying dataformatString. what is it showing wrong and what it does expect to show???